# Why is stack not using the defined extra dependency?

Tags: haskell-stack

I committed a change to Haskell's [opaleye](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye) project that I need for a project I am working on. The change is in version `0.6.7003.1`, which has not propagated to the nixos repository yet ([nixos.org](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#opaleye) shows its current version to be `0.6.7001.0`).

Since this needed dependency differs from the the resolver's LTS version, I have marked the extra dependency in `stack.yaml`:

```
packages:
- git@github.com:tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye.git
- commit: cf3296c5ffef58d36dd6b386ae53dff519ee47e9
```

I have also marked this version in the `build-depends` of my `project.cabal` file:

```
build-depends: opaleye >= 0.6.7003.1 && < 1
```

When I then attempted to build, I got the following error:

```
$ stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for taskmaster-0.1.0.0:
    opaleye must match >=0.6.7003.1 && <1, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version is 0.6.7003.1)
needed since taskmaster is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many
    complicated constraint errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/matthew/backup/taskmaster/taskmaster/stack.yaml:

opaleye-0.6.7003.1@sha256:914ac99c6f7ceea050df843ac31c33be0f6340bc0f05753c8fdfc18074fa9e5b

Plan construction failed.
```

(I do not understand where this long (>40 char) sha256 hash comes from).
I followed the advice and added the following to my `stack.yaml`.

```
extra-deps:
- opaleye-0.6.7003.1@sha256:914ac99c6f7ceea050df843ac31c33be0f6340bc0f05753c8fdfc18074fa9e5b
```

When I run `$ stack build` to build my project, the compiler attempts to build without showing any dependency errors. However, it strikes a type error that it would not if it were using the version of Opaleye containing my change. And, when I run `$ stack ghci` and import a relevant opaleye module, my change is not present. It appears that somehow stack is still using an older opaleye version. How can I get stack to use the more recent version of opaleye containing my change?
My attempts seem to have exhausted the options mentioned in the haskell-stack [documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/v1.0.2/yaml_configuration/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that stack's `extra-deps` suggestion was incorrect. I noticed an alternative format under [this stack github issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3873), gave it a try, and it happened to work for me. The working `extra-deps` format is listed below.

```
extra-deps:
- github: tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye
  commit: cf3296c5ffef58d36dd6b386ae53dff519ee47e9
```

Answer (score 1):

The hackage option is usually better than the github extra-dep.

The correct syntax for what you initially tried would be

```
extra-deps:
- git: https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye.git
  commit: cf3296c5ffef58d36dd6b386ae53dff519ee47e9
```

and the `github: tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye` version is just a shortcut.

The sha256 hash is the sha256sum of the cabal file corresponding to that version (and revision) of opaleye.

Given that version of opaleye is [already on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye), you should just be able to add the line suggested by stack. You may wish to try a `stack clean` after you make the change (though it shouldn't be necessary).

If you present more information, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Piggybacking on this... Is it necessary to add package to cabal file as well? Only then I can get it work but stack complains that cabal file was modified manually.

Comment: The `stack.yaml` file indicates which versions of dependencies you wish to build with. The `.cabal` file indicates which dependencies your package actually has. There is also the `package.yaml` file, which is equivalent in content to the `.cabal` file. Stack generates the `.cabal` file from the `package.yaml` file. If stack is warning that you modified the cabal file, you may wish to modify the `package.yaml` file instead. Does that help?